# Gravity forms how to display list of submitters on the post submitted page

Tags: custom-post-types, plugin-gravity-forms

- I am wondering if this could be done, we have thousands of
  restaurants on the wordpress site as a blog posts and one small
  request quote form on the bottom of every restaurant post page where
  job applicants asks for the job, they fill in the personal info about
  them and they send it to the author of the post and to the administrator
  via confirmation emails.
- For that purpose I have created job applicant's custom post type =
  portfolio and all submissions is also displayed on those portfolio
  CPT pages,
- After succesfull submission every job applicant's name is a title
  of every custom post type portfolio something like
  URL: http://www.mywebsite.com/portfolio/petra-newman/ Title: Petra Newman
- I would like to display those names = titles of the custom post
  types portfolio on those restaurants post pages where the form was submitted,
- **Purpose:** Other applicants can see how every virtual restaurant is
  requested.
- I was thinking to create custom post field for every restaurant and
  there store those submitters, so
- **Question is:** How can I tell to gravity form to store job applicants names = submitted form titles in those custom fields? Does
  exist any other option? How can I create list of submitters on every
  submitted post page?
- **Conclusion:** On every restaurant page where the form were submitted
  should be a list of applicant's names with links to every
  applicant portfolio.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you are embedding one form on many pages (or custom posts). It is possible to have Gravity Forms capture the **ID** of the referring page, as well as know it's *Title*. This is helpful in the email notification, for example, to understand on what page a contact was on when they decided to *make* contact. IE a form that is on every page... but what prompted them to finally fill it out?

With this same information, you can reference the referring page in order to cross reference that with a list comprised of the titles/names of the people who sent information while on that page.

Even if you didn't capture that data in the beginning, I am fairly certain that information is inside the actual gravity form lead description meta, in the database. Probably from that you would be able to access the relationship of submitter -> referring page.

Otherwise I would have it saved as `post_meta` in the future, as part of the post, so you don't have to dip into gforms tables.

Documentation on this hook will help: [Gform after submission - GravityForms](http://www.gravityhelp.com/documentation/page/Gform_after_submission)

Comment: Yes @GhostToast Yes the form will be in every post of every different restaurant _Documentation on this hook will help: Gform after submission - GravityForms_  You are perfectly right, there seems to be an answer! And you are also right that gravity forms memorize referrer in database and I think so that I can do everything after the job applicant submission(didn't know how), but this hopefully tells me your link now, thank you very much, unfortunately I am a newbie here I am not allowed to give you any points yet :(

Comment: You can choose this as correct answer though, if it was helpful.

Comment: Just did it @GhoastToast, I didn't know I can, yes it was very helpful